# Getting the error: "Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Options.". After adding the cdk-table explorer. Angular Project

Tags: angular

```
import { Mime } from '../../mime';
import { Exporter } from './exporter';

export declare abstract class FileExporter<T> implements Exporter<*T*> {
    constructor();
    export(rows: Array<any>, options?: T): void;
    abstract createContent(rows: Array<any>, options?: T): Promise<any>;
    abstract getMimeType(): Mime;
}
```

.

The curled object T is the one giving errors:
Error: node_modules/cdk-table-exporter/lib/services/exporters/worksheet-exporter.d.ts:8:73 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Options'.

8 export declare abstract class WorksheetExporter extends FileExporter {
~

node_modules/cdk-table-exporter/lib/services/exporters/worksheet-exporter.d.ts:8:49
8 export declare abstract class WorksheetExporter extends FileExporter {
~
This type parameter might need an `extends Options` constraint

Can anyone please assist with the issue. I am using Angular 15.2.0

Answer (score 0):

in tsconfig.ts file add this struction :

```
 "**compilerOptions**": {
     ...
    **"skipLibCheck": true,**
    ...
}
```